# How to link custom output protocol with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have created a custom ffmpeg output protocol and was able to build ffmpeg to include the protocol. The issue is that I did not like having to get a specific build of ffmpeg to use my protocol. Is there any way to add a custom protocol without having to mess with ffmpeg's source code and avoid its configuration and build steps?

I saw something online that suggested that I can register a custom protocol to ffmpeg somehow, but I have not been able to find anything on how to actually do it. I want to get this working on Windows and Linux so any insight on either would help.